# Sharepoint - referencing a file server folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, hyperlink, hybrid-solution, file-server

1. Is there a way in the current version of  Sharepoint online to reference/point to/link to a network folder. So for example a user of a company accesses the company Sharepoint site and on that site there is a button/link that if they click on will lead them to a folder on a company server. For instance on the company server there is a folder with pictures and videos.  When a company user logs into the company Sharepoint site they click on something and then the pictures and videos on the file server folder are visible to them?
2. If this can't be done directly with modern Sharepoint Online could it be done with a hybrid Sharepoint- on-premises and online versions -  in some way so there would be an on-premises Sharepoint that would have this capability and somehow the users could access those pictures on the company file server through that combination?
3. Worst case would it be possible to do this with on-premises only - so we would have two completely different Sharepoint sites - one built with on-premises Sharepoint and one with Sharepoint online and with the on-premises Sharepoint we could be able to accomplish what we want - a way for a company user to access  a folder on a network file server that has pictures/videos on it that they can view.

For historical, political reasons the folder in question can not be moved from its current file server location into Sharepoint - there is no point in pursuing that path even if it's technically feasible or not, it is not an option.

Please note that I have searched through all the suggested posts and none of them seemed to give a definitive answer to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can write api to reference to that folder. That API should be public and some encryption can be applied within that API so that folder is not accessed to everyone.

Once that API is created, you can integrate that API in SharePoint online.